# One handler for several events

Tags: c#, .net, events, handler

I have four events:

```
View.AdditionPerformed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.SubtractionPerformed+=new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.DivisionPerformed+=new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.MultiplyPerformed+=new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
```

and one method:

```
private void OnOperationPerformed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

How can I define which event raised my method? Something like this:

```
private void OnOperationPerformed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    switch(event)
     {
      case MultiplyPerformed:{}
      case DivisionPerformed:{}
      ...
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own `EventArgs` which has an `enum` inside, telling you the raised event.

```
enum MyEventEnum
{
    AdditionPerformed,
    SubtractionPerformed,
    DivisionPerformed,
    MultiplayPerformed
}
```

The `EventArgs`

```
class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventEnum EventRaised { get; set; }
}
```

Define the Handlers

```
View.AdditionPerformed += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.SubtractionPerformed+=new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.DivisionPerformed+=new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
View.MultiplyPerformed+=new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(OnOperationPerformed);
```

When you call them:

```
this.AdditionPerformed(this, new MyEventArgs 
    { EventRaised = MyEventEnum.AdditionPerformed };
```

I know it's pretty hardcoded, but there isn't any other way.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You don't need to pass the event "type" as an event argument as you already have one event per operation.

Comment: He wants to put all his operations to one method. This is the only way archieving it. I've never said I would do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using EventArgs, you could use your own event argument class to pass in the necessary data to make the choice inside the handler.

It would then become available on your e variable inside the handler.

Cheers